# Are the 4 sentences interchangeable enough that I can use whatever I want? - in which / when / in which to / to

Tags: sentence-construction

I like to go singing at karaoke with my friends.

> 1. It's a perfect time *to* let my hair down.
> 2. It's a perfect time *in which to* let my hair down.
> 3. It's a perfect time *where I can* let my hair down.
> 4. It's a perfect time *in which I can* let my hair down.

Are the 4 sentences interchangeable enough that I can use whichever I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About 2 and 4 ...

What must follow relative pronouns in general, including *which*, must be a clause with subject, verb, and anything the verb needs.  A mere phrase without a subject or verb can't follow *which*.  (*Which* is also an interrogative word but you are not asking a question in this example.)

> It's a perfect time in which I can let my hair down.

Because a clause must follow *which*, *to let my hair down* won't work because *let* here is an infinitive.

4 might be technically correct but sounds excessively wordy and awkward.  Avoid 4.

About 3 ...

*Time* is not a place, so *where* is not the appropriate pronoun to use to relate "I can let my hair down" it to "It's a perfect time."

Answer (score 0):

i think 
(1) Grammatically correct. 
(2) The Subject person "I" is missing, therefore to-infinitive is not correct.
(3) More and more acceptable nowadays, you can search "a time where" in google. 
(4) Grammatically correct.